# Regex match multiple meta tags in multi line string

Tags: html, regex, regex-greedy

I want to validate that a multi line string contains only meta tags in the format I specify. For example it can only contain one or more of these:

```
<meta property="og:[anything]" content="[anything]"/>
```

Where [anything] can be 0 or more of any character.

The meta tags may or may not me separated by new lines, so this is also ok:

```
<meta property="og:[anything]" content="[anything]"/>
<meta property="og:[anything]" content="[anything]"/>
<meta property="og:[anything]" content="[anything]"/>
```

Here is my current regex:

```
^(?:<meta [^>]*property=[\"']og:.+[\"'] [^>]*content=[\"']([^'^\"]+?)[\"'][^>]*>)(?:\n*)$
```

It works if the tags are on the same line, or if there's a tag with a newline, but not for tags on multiple lines.

How can I get it to match ***only*** these meta tags either on line or multiple lines?

Comment: I think I was able to get it to work, needed a "one or more" for the group itself:

^(<meta [^>]*property=[\"']og:.+[\"'] [^>]*content=[\"']([^'^\"]+?)[\"'][^>]*>\s*)*$

Comment: [Obligatory comment pointing out that you shouldn't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). More usefully - when you say `anything` is that really *anything*? Can the `[anything]` in the `property` property be replaced with, for example, `" content="blag"/>\r\n` because if so you're heading for a world of pain.

Comment: @Jeff - In this case, this is the only choice I've got. It's a CMS with a text area field, and the only way to enforce validation is with regex.

Comment: That's cool, as long as you know what you're getting in to :) sounds like it's probably not an area where maliciousness is something you'll need to seriously deal with, in which case an almost-solution is probably fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `^(?:\s*<meta\s*property=["']og:.+?["']\s*content=["'].+?["']\s*\/>\s*)+$`

See: https://regex101.com/r/iJ7fT8/2

Comment: I tried something similar, but it seems to be valid if invalid stuff is also inserted, i.e.:

<meta property="og:title" content="og desc"/>
invalid
//dangerous stuff
<meta property="og:title" content="og desc"/>

Comment: @drogon Oh, I think I misunderstood what you were asking for, try it now